# UDF reload in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, udf

I am using PySpark (inside an Jupyter Notebook, which connects to a Spark-cluster) and some UDFs. The UDF takes a list as the an additional parameter and I construct the UDF like this:

`my_udf = F.udf(partial(my_normal_fn, list_param=list), StringType())`

Everything works fine, with regard to executing the function. But I noticed that the UDF is never updated.
To clarify: When I update the `list`, for example by altering a element in the list, the UDF is not updated. The old version with the old list is still used. Even if I execute the whole notebook again.
I have to restart the Jupyter Kernel in order to use new version of the list. Which is really annoying...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

My `my_normal_fn` did have the following signature:

```
def my_normal_fn(x, list_param=[]):
    dosomestuffwith_x_and_list_param
```

Changing it to

```
def my_normal_fn(x, list_param):
    dosomestuffwith_x_and_list_param
```

Did the trick. See [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) for more information.

Thanks to user Drjones78 of the SparkML-Slack channel.